# Removing built-in git from El Capitan

Tags: macos, git

I installed latest version of `git` into `/usr/local/bin` and change `$PATH` so that new version is picked up when using shell. Can I remove old version that is in `/usr/bin` directory ? I am afraid to do it because something could break in the system maybe. I am just curious about this.

Comment: The short answer is NO. Do not remove `git` from `/usr/bin`. If you did then you are now responsible for maintaining the system. At any point a software update could re-install the file. Adjust your PATH and leave it alone.

Comment: This might also help you with shuting down your mac http://askubuntu.com/questions/578144/why-doesnt-running-sudo-shutdown-now-shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good answer over on Stack Overflow:  [How to upgrade Git to latest version on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957862/how-to-upgrade-git-to-latest-version-on-mac-os-x)

Basically, you want to use brew to install and manage your (separate) git installation and leave the one provided by Apple alone.  You will obviously have to have [Home Brew](http://brew.sh/) installed initially.

To install:

```
brew install git
```

To update:

```
brew upgrade git
```